# Creating a Gmod Lua Timer

Tags: timer, lua, garrys-mod

I was wondering how to create a timer in lua that works also in servers with no players on.
Timer.Simple or Timer.Create don't work, they need CurTime().
How could I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Well one option is always to set the convar `sv_hibernate_think` to 1.
That is also the option provided on the official Wiki [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNQTR.png).

Answer (score -1):

Depends on what's available.  You likely can't import any extra libs, and Lua's capabilities have 'prolly been nerfed.

If standard clock capabilities still exist, you can do something with

```
local init, pause = os.clock(), 3
while os.clock() -init < pause do end
```

I don't know your exact use; could be made into a function if need be.  That will eat up clock cycles.  If coroutines exist, you might be able to have another script runing in the background while occasionally checking on timer.